# my sql left join does not return all rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the  sql query to display all the days of the month using a brd_day table(this table contains all the days for the year) and brr_transactions (all the transactions are in this table) and BRR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHIES (account details).

My query currently only displays the rows where there is a transaction in the month, but I am trying to to display all the rows for the month, even if there are no transaction on a day.

Here is my code:

**SQL Code:**

```
select dy.day_date,
       SUM(ISNULL(CASE BRR_TRANSACTIONS.SIDE WHEN 'CASHBOOK' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) "Q_LINK",
       SUM(ISNULL(CASE BRR_TRANSACTIONS.SIDE WHEN 'STATEMENT' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) "ZEUS_DBT010",
       sum(ISNULL(CASE BRR_TRANSACTIONS.SIDE WHEN 'CASHBOOK' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) - 
       sum(ISNULL(CASE BRR_TRANSACTIONS.SIDE WHEN 'STATEMENT' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) "Difference"
from   BRD_DAY dy
       left join brr_transactions on brr_transactions.transaction_date = dy.day_date
                                     and dy.DAY_DATE >= convert(datetime, '20140601', 112) 
                                     and dy.DAY_DATE <= convert(datetime, '20140630', 112)
       inner join BRR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHIES on brr_transactions.account_id = BRR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHIES.ACCOUNT_ID
                                             and BRR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHIES.ACCOUNT_ID = 1911
GROUP by dy.day_date
```

Results:

```
Day_date                   q_link           zeus_dbt             difference 
2014-06-02 00:00:00.000 25560.330000      0.000000            25560.330000
2014-06-03 00:00:00.000 129292.860000     0.000000            129292.860000
2014-06-04 00:00:00.000 0.000000          10966.840000       -10966.840000
2014-06-05 00:00:00.000 0.000000          26742.060000       -26742.060000
2014-06-06 00:00:00.000 26883.480000      26883.480000        0.000000
2014-06-09 00:00:00.000 1305.730000       1305.700000         0.030000
2014-06-10 00:00:00.000 7104.150000       7104.150000         0.000000
2014-06-11 00:00:00.000 1080.270000       0.000000            1080.270000
2014-06-12 00:00:00.000 2929.600000       0.000000           2929.600000           
2014-06-13 00:00:00.000 342047.930000     0.000000            342047.930000
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try left join instead of Inner join, i.e. the second one..

Comment: @Tristan thanks for the input, but i get all the dates from 1999 to 2014 when i left join the 2nd one also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either make both joins `left` joins, or you should make the `inner` join to the right hand table logically occur before the `left` join, as:

```
select dy.day_date,
   SUM(ISNULL(CASE tr.SIDE WHEN 'CASHBOOK' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) "Q_LINK",
   SUM(ISNULL(CASE tr.SIDE WHEN 'STATEMENT' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) "ZEUS_DBT010",
   sum(ISNULL(CASE tr.SIDE WHEN 'CASHBOOK' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) - 
   sum(ISNULL(CASE tr.SIDE WHEN 'STATEMENT' THEN AMOUNT END, 0)) "Difference"
from   BRD_DAY dy
   left join brr_transactions tr
   inner join BRR_ACCOUNT_HIERARCHIES ach
       on tr.account_id = ach.ACCOUNT_ID
          and ach.ACCOUNT_ID = 1911
       on tr.transaction_date = dy.day_date
where
     dy.DAY_DATE >= convert(datetime, '20140601', 112) 
     and dy.DAY_DATE <= convert(datetime, '20140630', 112)
```

I've also moved these last two conditions (just on `dy`) down into the `WHERE` clause, since I think they're meant to apply to the entire query, not just as a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Make your second join a left join as well. Right now you tell sql server to filter the results of your dy+tran results by those records that have a link to hierarchies.